# Spurious error on <style> tag using sublime-linter csslinter

Tags: css, html, sublimetext3, csslint

As a relative newbie to sublime 3 I am trying to set up the sublime-linter plugin to check HTML and CSS files.

The issue I have is that having installed HTMLTidy and CSSLint and the relevant plugins that in HTML files the csslint is throwing validation errors for the  element in my html pages.

> 'Unexpected token '<' at line 8, col 1. '

I am using Sublime 3 (Build 3083) on Windows 7 with v0.10.0 of csslint and HTML Tidy for Windows version 5.1.9 from the HTML5 Bundle

So for example if I have an html file like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is a title</title>
    <style>
       h1 {color:red;}
       p {color:blue;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>A heading</h1>
    <p>A paragraph.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then the opening <style> tag is marked as an error as is the closing one.

By using 'Toggle Linter' to enable and disable the SublimeLinter options I can see that these errors are only generated when csslint is enabled.

From reading through the notes for the linters and SublimeLinter I can suppress this behavior by adding a rule to the csslint section of my SublimeLinter preferences of the form

```
         "ignore_match": [
                ".*Unexpected token.*"
            ],
```

This fixes this error, but has the side effect that a  new warning is thrown on the first style element - in the above example the h1 element of the form

> Heading {h1} should not be qualified

Which I can only remove either by creating a dummy first line in my style element.

My questions would be:

- Is there a sensible way to prevent the second error when a CSS element is in the line immediately after the style tag, without preventing genuine CSS issues from being highlighted?
- Should I be formatting my HTML differently to avoid these validation errors?
- Is there a way to avoid the issue by using a different set of lint tools which would still provide HTML5 and CSS validation automatically in Sublime?

Thanks